# Cannot download C#/.Net (Xamarin v4.2.1) on visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a legacy project built on Xamarin Android target framework 19. The apk is installed on a custom device that runs Android KitKat. I am trying to build the project with VS2019 but I face some compatibility issues, hence I am trying to install VS2015. But the Xamarin studio URL seems to be changed with the recent update from Microsoft chance I see the following issue.

> C#/.NET (Xamarin v4.2.1) This product did not download successfully.
> HTTP status 404 .The requested url does not exist on the server.

It looks like the visual studio 2015 iso file doesn't contain xamarin packages.
Can anyone help me to istall xamarin on VS2015 or share me iso with xamarin included?
[image]

Comment: Hey @santos, Is this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c357e649-d070-4add-93f8-571f8fd8abc3/error-while-install-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015?forum=xamarinvisualstudio) of your problem.

Comment: @HirenPatel, I believe not. I assume visual studio 2015 was downloading xamarin packages from xamarin official website. As the official website is redirected to Microsoft, vs2015 was unable to fetch data. So, I am trying to find a complete offline installation guide.

Comment: I managed to run my project from Visual Studio 2017. Downloading old SDK and building projects works for me.